# Changing ORDER BY causes "error converting data type"

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to preface, I didn't write this.  I inherited it earlier today, and I've been fighting to find a solution.   The below codebase works - with the exception that the Cost Per Square Foot is returning in Alpha order rather than numeric.

```
SELECT 
  CTE.Suite, CTE.Building, CS.Address, CS.City, CS.State, CTE.Tenant,
  CTE.AverageCharges, CTE.SQFT, CTE.CostSQFT, CTE.TenantType
FROM cteInvoices as CTE
   ...
ORDER BY 
  CASE @Order
       WHEN 'Suite' THEN CTE.Suite
       WHEN 'Cost' THEN cast(CTE.costSQFT as varchar)
  END
```

I changed the end case to the following:

```
 ORDER BY 
  CASE @Order
       WHEN 'Suite' THEN CTE.Suite
       WHEN 'Cost' THEN CTE.costSQFT
   END
```

That fixed the cost sorting, however, when I choose to sort by Suite, I get:

```
  Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure rCostSQFTcsort, Line 17
  Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

I've been working on this most of the evening, and nothing I seem to do fixes it - if anything it tends to make things worse. I'm hoping a second set of eyes may shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Re: `cast as varchar` please read: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If those aren't convertible to the same type, you may need to separate them into two separate clauses. The reason is that `CASE` is an expression that returns a value of a single data type, and the data type presented by all potential options must be convertible. If there's no `ELSE` then `NULL` is returned, so it will order all rows the same for that "branch":

```
 ORDER BY 
  CASE @Order
       WHEN 'Suite' THEN CTE.Suite END,
  CASE @Order
       WHEN 'Cost' THEN CTE.costSQFT END;
```

It may be possible that you could explicitly convert one of these, but that may change its meaning (e.g. you probably still want `11.0` to sort *after* `9.0`, and converting both to a string won't do that.